# UK visa exemptions residence permit EEA

Tags: visas, uk, transit, belgium, ecuador

Do i need a transit visa for a flight that goes from Belgium to Ecuador and has a stop on London? I have a Belgian Residence Permit valid for a year because I'm a student, I have only the Residence Permit card and the visa in my passport is expired.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What's youre citizenship? Do you intend to exit the airport?  Do you arrive and leave from the same airport?

Comment: Your residence permit was valid for a longer duration that the visa? Can you mention exact dates?

Comment: @AdityaSomani Exact Dates may not matter as long as it is valid at the time of the travel.

Comment: In addition are you traveling on a Single Itinerary or did you buy tickets TO London and TO Ecuador separately?

Comment: @Karlson I felt it would simplify things and avoid confusion which we sometimes face.

Comment: @Karlson None of this matters in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Having a “**common format**” residence permit from an EEA country does allow you [to transit in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/275926/Charging_Guide_Jan_2014_Version_6.pdf) (see in particular pp. 7-9) even if you are a DATV national (which is the case of citizens of Ecuador).

A common format residence permit [looks like this](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/BEL-HO-03002/image-85936.html).